# I have my type author and i put it in map in my table. How can I get access to map author, delete eg. firstname or delete lastname etc.?

Tags: cassandra

My type:

```
CREATE TYPE author(
    firstname text, 
    lastname text
);
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE ksiazki(
   publishing text, 
   origin text, 
   id int, 
   title text, 
   author map<text, frozen<author>>,
   categories set<text>,
   pages int,
   PRIMARY KEY ((publishing,origin), id, title)
);
```

Comment: You can't update or delete firstname or lastname from frozen author. you have to update or delete  that whole author value

Comment: What is the syntax to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update or delete firstname or lastname from frozen author. you have to update or delete that whole author value

You can insert data using.

```
 INSERT INTO ksiazki (publishing , origin , id , title , author ) VALUES ( 'pub', 'orig', 1, 'Title', {'author 1' : {firstname:'MD', lastname : 'Test'}})  ;
```

If you want to change 'author 1' name just update with this query :

```
UPDATE ksiazki SET author = author +  {'author 1' : {firstname:'Ashraful', lastname : 'Islam'}} where publishing = 'pub' and origin = 'orig' and id = 1 and title = 'Title';
```

If you want to add another author 'author 2' use this query :

```
UPDATE ksiazki SET author = author +  {'author 2' : {firstname:'Ashraful', lastname : 'Alom'}} where publishing = 'pub' and origin = 'orig' and id = 1 and title = 'Title';
```

If you want to delete 'author 2' use this query :

```
DELETE author['author 2'] FROM ksiazki where publishing = 'pub' and origin = 'orig' and id = 1 and title = 'Title';
```